# How can I check for a string over multiple lines and quote it?

Tags: php, regex

I have to fix a YAML-file. I have to check the file for the text-field (I can ignore all other fields). If the content isn't quoted, I want to set these quotes.

```
text: - Any text
```

Should return

```
text: "- Any text"
```

So I check line by line of the original file to create a new file:

```
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    $re = "/text:\s*\K([^\"]+?)$/m";
    $subst = "\"$1\""; 
    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $line);
    fwrite($new_file, $result); // Write line to a new file     
}
```

But it doesn't work if the text has more then one line.

This is what happens at the moment:

```
text: - Any text\n
    which has more
    then one
    line
format: do nothing with that
```

This should be:

```
text: "- Any text\n
    which has more
    then one
    line"
format: do nothing with that
```

How can I check over multiple lines and add quotes if they are missing?
If the quotes are already set, nothing should happen to these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$result = preg_replace('/text:\s*\K(.+?)(?=\R^\w+: )/ms', "$1", $line);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ3jR4/1)

`(?=\R^\w+: )` is a lookahead that will make sure to match until next line is some `word:`

Answer (score 0):

```
text:\s*\K([\s\S]+?)(?=\n[^\s]+|$)
```

Try this.Replace by `"$1"`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/14

```
$re = "/text:\\s*\\K([\\s\\S]+?)(?=\\n[^\\s]+|$)/i";
$str = "text: - Any text\ntext: - Any text\n\n which has more\n then one\n line\nformat: do nothing with that\ntext: - Any text";
$subst = "\"$1\"";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
 $str="Text: -any text";
 $pattren=array();
 $pattern[0]="/\-/";
 $replacement=array();
 $replacement[0]="\"-";
  echo preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str);?>
```

> **Demo** :  https://eval.in/299211